# calculate sum recursive from a stack

Tags: recursion, stack

Why is the below code printing "6" ? I would have expected "13" as a result.

```
        void testSum(){
            Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack();
            myStack.add(3);
            myStack.add(4);
            myStack.add(6);
            System.out.println(calculateSum(myStack, 0));
        }

        Integer calculateSum(Stack<Integer> myStack, int sum) {
            if (!myStack.empty()) {
                sum = sum + myStack.pop();
                calculateSum(myStack, sum);
            }
            return sum;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` is passed by value. If you want to imitate passing by reference, you may create a wrapper class for integer, like below:

```
class IntWrapper
{
 int n;
}
```

and modify your code accordingly:

```
static void testSum(){
    Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack();
    myStack.add(3);
    myStack.add(4);
    myStack.add(6);
    System.out.println(calculateSum(myStack, new IntWrapper()));
}

static Integer calculateSum(Stack<Integer> myStack, IntWrapper sum) {
    if (!myStack.empty()) {
        sum.n = sum.n + myStack.pop();
        calculateSum(myStack, sum);
    }
    return sum.n;
}
```

Comment: and why a Integer doesn't work instead of a int ? is it because of automatic unboxing ?

Comment: @bluesony because you can't modify Integer's value, you need to declare a new Integer

Answer (score 2):

What mangusta said is correct.
You could do something like this too:

```
static void testSum(){
        Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack();
        myStack.add(3);
        myStack.add(4);
        myStack.add(6);
        System.out.println(calculateSum(myStack));
    }

static Integer calculateSum(Stack<Integer> myStack) {
    if (!myStack.empty())
        return myStack.pop() + calculateSum(myStack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i like it better

Comment: @bluesony it's more compact but it doesn't explain the difference between passing by value and passing by reference in which you have serious knowledge gaps